# detect when mouse cursor is over an irregular shape picture in Qt5 and QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm developing a little application with Qt5 and QML (QtCreator and C++).

I would like to display a map with countries and when user passes the mouse over a country I would like to change the color of the country, thought it would be easy, and it is if all countries were rectangles.

```
    Image {
    id: mycountry
    width: 250
    height: 250
    source: "images/myCountry_gray.png"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled : true
        onEntered: {
            region.source = "images/myCountry_red.png"
        }
        onExited: {
            region.source = "images/myCountry_gray.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, countries have irregular shapes, and I would like only highlight the country when mouse cursor is inside its frontier

Have you some idea how to develop that? I think it won't be possible using QML alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#contains) to construct the shape of each country. You can do this using [moveTo()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#moveTo-2) and [lineTo()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#lineTo-2). Once you have this, make it a member variable of a custom [QQuickItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html) - let's call it `CountryItem`. You could make the image a child of this item after exposing it to QML via `CountryMapModule`:

```
import CountryMapModule 1.0

CountryItem {
    implicitWidth: mapImage.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: mapImage.implicitHeight

    Image {
        id: mapImage
        source: ":/images/australia.png"
    }
}
```

Override [QQuickItem::mouseMoveEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#mouseMoveEvent) to allow the item to check for mouse movement. The [contains()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#contains) function of `QPainterPath` can then be used to check if the mouse is inside it. You may need to scale the path to fit the size of the image.

Comment: Very nice and neat approach!

Comment: I just wanted to say that I got it working but I didnt' use QPainterPath but QImage. Checking whether the mouse coordinates are over a pixel with alpha component equal to 0 or not.